# Pointer is missing a nullability type specifier (_Nonnull, _Nullable, or _Null_unspecified) After Adding Swift Module to Project in XCode

Tags: objective-c, xcode13

I started getting this error all over the place and it's really annoying because I wasn't getting it UNTIL I added a Swift module (class extension) to my Objective-C project and then deleted it again.  What setting was changed that caused this compiler warning to start appearing all of a sudden?

Pointer is missing a nullability type specifier (_Nonnull, _Nullable, or _Null_unspecified)

Comment: That helped, thank you.  Though I'm curious as to why this started happening only AFTER I added a Swift module to my project.

Comment: For a brand new project the warning is thrown whenever an Objective-C interface is wrapped with `NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN`/`NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END` by default (and ignored otherwise) no matter if it has had any Swift classes imported or not. I **assume** your project was just created a while ago, and importing a Swift entity refreshed some Xcode perception of it.

Comment: Interesting.  The mysteries of Xcode.  Thank you for your explanation.